# Why did splice delete only last element and don't work by key?

Tags: reactjs

```
deleteProtoItem = (protoKey) => {
        return e => {
            if (!isUndefined(e)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            const {protocol} = this.state;
            modalConfirm(`<div>Вы уверены что хотите удалить эту строку?</div>`, {
                cancel: "Не удалять",
                ok: "Удалить"
            }).then(() => {
                protocol.tasks.splice(protoKey, 1);
                this.setState({protocol}, () => {
                });
            }).catch(handleErrorResponse);
        };
    };
```

When I delete element don't mind what key number it have 0 or 3, anyway splice remove only last element.

Protocol.tasks array

[image: x]

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because `protoKey is undefined`, try `passing protoKey to the callback`

```
deleteProtoItem = (protoKey) => {
        return e => {
            if (!isUndefined(e)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            const {protocol} = this.state;
            modalConfirm(`<div>Вы уверены что хотите удалить эту строку?</div>`, {
                cancel: "Не удалять",
                ok: "Удалить"
            }).then((protoKey) => {
                protocol.tasks.splice(protoKey, 1);
                this.setState({protocol}, () => {
                });
            }).catch(handleErrorResponse);
        };
    };
```

Comment: no i can show u console.log(protokey) it work correctly (( i dont know  why wouldt it happen(

Comment: when i use protoKey in then() i have undefinded but if dont do it i have a number